# How to download the file stored in azure blob to local machine using javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading all the files in Azure blob storage. I am working on Dynamics 365 and want to download the file stored in Azure blob when I click the button in my Dynamics environment.

```
function getSelectedItems(selectedItems) { 
  for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++)
  {
     var selectedItem = selectedItems[i];
     // Here you can use the information below to open a new window or whatever!
     alert("Id=" + selectedItem.Id + "\nName=" + selectedItem.Name + "\nTypeCode=" + selectedItem.TypeCode.toString() + "\nTypeName=" + selectedItem.TypeName);
         
     var new_fileName = selectedItem.Id;
     var new_fileurl = '';
        
     getUrlOfAttachmentFileFromBlob(new_fileurl,new_fileName);
  }
}
```

```
function getUrlOfAttachmentFileFromBlob(new_fileurl,new_fileName) {
  var fileHyperlink = '';
  var blobUri = 'https://' + 'Storage_Account_Name' + '.blob.core.windows.net';
  var containerName = 'trial';
  var sas_token = 'sastoken' ;
    
  var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sas_token);
  //.withFilter(new AzureStorage.Blob.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());

  var downloadLink = blobService.getUrl(new_fileName, new_fileurl.replace('/'+containerName+'/',''), sas_token);

  if (downloadLink != null)
  {
      alert("Link " + downloadLink);
      downloadURI(downloadLink, new_fileName);
  }
}
```

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute('download', name);
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

I tried this code, but it's not working.

To add more details, I am calling the `getSelectedItems` function when I click the button inside the Dynamics environment. In this function, I am also getting the unique ID of the selected row in the grid. The unique ID is the name of the file in Azure blob storage.

Can you please provide me some reference on how can I download the files to the local machine using JavaScript?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code instead of its screenshot.

Comment: Also include the code for generating the SAS token.

Comment: Use the Azure Storage JavaScript v12 library. to download the bob refer this link     [ 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-javascript    ]   There are some examples check with this  link[ https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/basic.js#